How would I export the vertex groups data from the "spreadsheet" option in Blender?
I have several vertex groups separated on my 3D model and I would like to export the spreadsheet that reflects the x,y, and z data along with the vertex groups data. I have already been able to export only the x,y, and z data as a .csv file using an open source code I found on here. However, I haven't been able to find any solutions to export the table shown below of the vertex groups. In this example listed below, I would want to export the area of the table with 'Ears', 'Mouth', 'Eyes', and 'Face' as a .csv file.

This is the code I have tried from Blender artists iceythe Kaoi:
import bpy
import os


def write_verts():
    obj = bpy.context.object

    if obj is None or obj.type != "MESH":
        return

    # Output geometry
    obj_eval = obj.evaluated_get(bpy.context.view_layer.depsgraph)
    filepath = "vertices.csv"
    
    with open(filepath, "w") as file:
        # Write the header, pos x | pos y | pos z
        file.write("pos x,pos y,pos z\n")

        for v in obj_eval.data.vertices:
            # ":.3f" means to use 3 fixed digits after the decimal point.
            file.write(f",".join(f"{c:.3f}" for c in v.co) + "\n")

    print(f"File was written to {os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filepath)}")

if __name__ == "__main__":

    write_verts()

Can be found at: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-export-an-objects-vertex-positions/1397962/16

What have you tried as far? Can you share the code that works for you with other data you need?

Also "export the spreadsheet that reflects the x,y, and z data along with the vertex groups data." - what do you mean? How should it reflect it? In what specific format? Do you need it in the same format as what you see in the Spreadsheet editor?

Yes, I would like the format look just like the previous image in a .csv file. I attached the code I have tried to the previous post

Every vertex has a list of groups that it belongs to, so in the loop
for v in obj_eval.data.vertices:

you can access these lists, they are simply v.groups. If the vert has a group in that list, you can access its index with v.groups[0].group. 0 here would be the first group in that list and it will not exist for verts that have no groups and there can be multiple groups assigned to a vert. You can access the weight of any particular group - v.groups[0].weight. You need to write a header for each existing group and you can get a list of all object groups - that's obj_eval.vertex_groups.
How do I know all this? Well, I didn't, I checked in the Python console using its autocomplete functionality( Tab ):

You can do the same to explore Blender's Python API. Then it's just a matter of using regular Python functionality to put the data into the format you want.

I keep receiving the error message of "TypeError: bpy_prop_collection[key]: MeshVertex.groups does not support string lookups" when trying to use 'v.groups'. Also receiving an error of "AttributeError: 'VertexGroup' object has no attribute 'groups' " when trying to use 'for v in obj_eval.vertex_groups'. Any advice on what I could be doing wrong?

I suspect you are using a string where you are supposed to use an integer and you are probably trying to access groups attribute of some group that does not exist.
